# yii2 not installing with correct permissions with composer

Tags: php, yii, composer-php, yii2-basic-app, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running windows 10 with the ubuntu subsystem installed as my localhost. I have composer installed on that and when I try to install the yii2 basic application it goes through the process correctly but when i open the yii2 basic application in my browser I get:

Failed to change permissions for directory "/mnt/c/Users/andre/zype/staff-tools/web/assets/89851207": chmod(): Operation not permitted

If I then change permissions on the yii2 installation file structure with

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .

the application loads but the web/assets folders are missing so my application has no styling. I am unsure if this is a composer issue or a yii2 issue but it looks like permissions to me.

Comment: It may also be a Ubuntu Subsystem. I had troubles with that a few weeks ago, doing rather strange things

Comment: Did you run the install using sudo?

Comment: I used to run compser as sudo but have changed it to now run not as root I still get the issues. Should composer create files with the owner www-data or my user? All files seems to be own by me after composer install

Comment: It should probably be www-data, depending on how you serve your localhost (if webserver: www-data)

Comment: Looks like chown and chmod dont work in WSL all files are actually controlled by windows

Comment: yes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permission of 'assets' folder most likely to 777 (all users can access this file)

> your-project/web/assets

Well this solution works for Linux users. Will require to check for windows

Follow Steps

Step 1- Install Composer (I installed it through bash)

Step 2- Now in cmd use following command

> composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic yii2-basic-check

Output (Last Lines)-

> chmod('runtime', 0777)...done.
>
> chmod('web/assets', 0777)...done.
>
> chmod('yii', 0755)...done.

Step 3 - Open "http://localhost/yii2-basic-check/web/" URL in browser.
It worked fine for me

Comment: Check the answer I've modified it.

Comment: is this using WSL?

Comment: What is WSL? I didn't get you.

Comment: windows sub-system for linix

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** Windows Subsystem for Linux has many serious problems with file permission. So, I advise not to install Linux programs and it's files in Windows drives i.e. DRVFS (`/mnt/c`). Also as PHP frameworks need many files, it will be better if you install distributions in another internal NTFS drives other that C:\ drive.

**Steps:** Place/clone the required project files/repositories in current user's home folder e.g. `/root`, `/home`, `/home/user`. Do not place the files in C:\ drive aka. `/mnt/c` otherwise WSL will not follow their permissions correctly. Here is an example of the installation procedure from [YiiFramework: The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation).

- Install required packages: `sudo apt-get install php php-cli php-common php-mbstring php-xml php-zip zip unzip`
- Go to user folder: `cd ~`
- Download composer: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
- Install yii2-basic: `~/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic`
- Go to project folder: `cd ~/basic`
- Run PHP server: `php yii serve`
- Open server in browser at `localhost:8080` (default port 8080).